# JSON file formatting for legibility

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a .json file that currently looks as so in txt editor

```
{"a": [1,2,3], "b":[2,3], "c":[1,3,5]}
```

Essentially its holding a dictionary at the moment. I was wondering if there was a way to use Python to "beautify" the .json file by adding newlines every key.
Using json indent results in:

```
{
   "a": [
          1,2,3
        ],
   "b":[
          2,3
       ],
   "c":[
          1,3,5
       ]
}
```

So now I want to strip the newlines and form:

```
{
   "a": [1,2,3],
   "b":[2,3],
   "c":[1,3,5]
}
```

Comment: `json.dumps` has an `indent` argument

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but you could use string replacing to format the json, something like:

```
with open('foo.json', 'r') as handle:
    parsed = json.load(handle)

string_json = json.dumps(parsed, indent=0, sort_keys=True)
string_replaced = string_json.replace("\n", "").replace("{", "{\n").replace("],", "],\n").replace("}", "\n}")
```

this will give your desired output, but not sure how extensible it will be, as it uses simple string matching

Answer (score 0):

For a file data.json in the same directory as your python script

```
{"a": [1,2,3], "b":[2,3], "c":[1,3,5]}
```

You can read the original JSON and then over-write the original file with the "beautified" version.

```py
import json
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
```

New data.json

```
{
  "a": [
    1, 
    2, 
    3
  ], 
  "b": [
    2, 
    3
  ], 
  "c": [
    1, 
    3, 
    5
  ]
}
```